# How to run report and dashboard for real time event monitoring data

Tags: reporting, dashboard, streaming-api, custom-reports, event-monitoring

I have enabled real time event monitoring in production org and now requirement is to run report for couple of events(URIEvent,APIEvent,LightningURIEvents)

I dont see we can create report on big objects .Can someone please let me know how we can build report and dashboard for Real time event monitoring in salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can achieve this using reports & dashboards.
The event monitoring objects (URIEvent, APIEvent etc) are not supported for reports & dashboards and are not real-time. You can however view them in Einstein Analytics (using the license that comes with Event Monitoring) but again this is not real-time, the data is collated each night and can be imported to analytics studio each day.
I think if you want to do anything real-time with event monitoring you will need to use the streaming API to access the relevant stream channel (URIEventStream, APIEventStream etc) via a CometD subscription.

Comment: N.B. LightningUriEventStream are real-time events as of Winter 20 but not reportable as noted; see [SFDC doc View Big Object Data in Reports and Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_query_and_report.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can run an Async SOQL query on URIEvent, APIEvent, and LightningURIEvents Big Objects. Then use dashboards / reports / EA on the custom objects that the Async SOQL query saved the data to.

Otherwise, as the previous answer said, you can use EventLogFiles + Einstein Analytics to analyze ELF based URIEvent, Api Events & lightning events.